# DataTable Delete Row and AcceptChanges

Tags: c#, datatable

**DataTable DT**

```
num     type    name
===================================
001     A       Peter
002     A       Sam
003     B       John
```

---

```
public static void fun1(ref DataTable DT, String TargetType)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string type = DT.Rows[i]["type"];

        if (type == TargetType)
        {
            /**Do Something**/
            DT.Rows[i].Delete();
        }
    }
    DT.AcceptChanges();
}
```

My function get specific data rows in datatable according to the TargetType and use their info to do something. After the datarow is read (match the target type), it will be deleted.

However, the row is deleted immediately after .Delete() execute, so the location of the next row (by i) is incorrect.

For example, if TargetType is A. When i=0, the "Peter" row is deleted after .Delete executed. Then when i=1, I suppose it will locate the "Sam" row but it actually located "John" row because "Peter" row is deleted.

Is there any problem in my codes?

Comment: I think when type==TargetType and it deletes the row then you should decrement the  value of i by 1, so that when it deletes i=0 then the row at 1=1 moves to i=0 it will then check and delete the row, there is one more check you need to imply if row at i=0 deletes then rather decrementing you should set the value of i=0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Delete method doesn't remove the row from the `Rows` collection. It marks it with the `Deleted` `RowState`. The row is removed from the DataTable's collection after the call to `AcceptChanges`.
So, inside a normal for loop there is no side effect on the count of the elements

However, keep in mind:

After the call to Delete any kind of access to the now Deleted row will raise an exception.

```
 DT.Rows[i].Delete();
 string test = DT.Rows[i][0].ToString(); // Will raise an exception
```

and, according to MSDN, a foreach loop with a delete inside it will trigger an exception

See

[DataRow.RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx)
[DataRow.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ya, there is a problem in your code. You should call `DT.AcceptChanges()` method before for loop. It will change the rowstate of all the rows added from `Added` to `Unchanged`. Now if you call the `Delete` method , it will not delete it from datatable untill you call the `AcceptChanges` method and also your index will remain the same and not point to next row.

If the RowState of the row is `Added`, the RowState becomes `Detached` and the row is removed from the table when you call AcceptChanges.